# Настроить пересечение и алиасы фильтров Yandex Maps API ObjectManager

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Имею карту, заполняемую внешними json-данными через Object Manager.
По инструкции добавил фильтры. Не очень понимаю, как сделать, чтобы они работали одновременно, по пересечению. Один проверяет obj.options.unittype, второй obj.options.district:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.72, 37.5],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl']
        }, {suppressMapOpenBlock: true}, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 64,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: false,
            // Макет метки кластера pieChart.
            clusterIconLayout: "default#pieChart",
            // Радиус диаграммы в пикселях.
            clusterIconPieChartRadius: 23,
            // Радиус центральной части макета.
            clusterIconPieChartCoreRadius: 16,
            // Ширина линий-разделителей секторов и внешней обводки диаграммы.
            clusterIconPieChartStrokeWidth: 2
        });


    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    //objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redDotIcon');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    //## Фильтр по районам
    // Создадим пункты выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems1 = ['ВАО', 'ЗАО', 'ЗелАО', 'САО', 'СВАО', 'СЗАО', 'ТиНАО', 'ЦАО', 'ЮАО', 'ЮВАО', 'ЮЗАО']
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: true
                }
            })
        }),
        // Теперь создадим список.
        listBoxControl1 = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Районы',
                title: 'Районы'
            },
            items: listBoxItems1,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: false,
                filters: listBoxItems1.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl1);

    // Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка.
    listBoxControl1.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
        var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
        var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl1.state.get('filters'));
        filters[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
        listBoxControl1.state.set('filters', filters);
    });

    var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl1.state);
    filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
        // Применим фильтр.
        objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction1(filters));
    });

    function getFilterFunction1(categories){
        return function(obj){
            var content = obj.options.district;
            return categories[content]
        }
    }

    //## Фильтр по типу
    // Создадим пункты выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems2 = ['Библиотеки', 'Дома культуры', 'Учреждения (биб)', 'Учреждения (дк)', 'Дирекция']
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: true
                }
            })
        }),
        // Теперь создадим список.
        listBoxControl2 = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Фильтр по типу',
                title: 'Фильтр по типу'
            },
            items: listBoxItems2,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: false,
                filters: listBoxItems2.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl2);

    // Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка.
    listBoxControl2.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
        var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
        var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl2.state.get('filters'));
        filters[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
        listBoxControl2.state.set('filters', filters);
    });

    var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl2.state);
    filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
        // Применим фильтр.
        objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction2(filters));
    });

    function getFilterFunction2(categories){
        return function(obj){
            var content = obj.options.unittype;
            return categories[content]
        }
    }



    //Подгрузим данные из АИС
    $.ajax({
        url: "json_map.xsp"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });




}
```

UPD: Про алиасы. Не могу понять, есть ли в API-классах ListBoxItem возможность визуально отображать одно значение, а передавать другое.

Answer (score 1):

Для фильтров можно указывать логические условия, например:

```
objectManager.setFilter('properties.type == "кафе" || properties.type == "аптека"');
```

[Описание в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/?from=SO#setFilter)

Comment: Да, я это видел, как предлагаете в данном случае это использовать?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю. Нужно ли мне два filterMonitor'а и как мне обрабатывать изменение одного фильтра, чтобы учитывать состояние второго?

Comment: @AntonNazarov вам нужно следить за изменениями обоих параметров и в ответ на изменение любого из них применять соответствующий фильтр

Comment: Могу ли я повесить отслеживание изменений обоих фильтров на один монитор? И как совместить функции для передачи состояния ItemList'ов в setFilter, чтобы они учитывали оба списка? Если не трудно, подкорректируйте, пожалуйста, мой образец.